# Powershell Script to md5 hash checksum only new files

Tags: powershell

the powershell script im using

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\MyMediaFiles' -Recurse -File | 
    Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'D:\MediaHashes.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

lets say I run this script on my Media folder and then 2 days later I added 20 more videos to the folder how can I make powershell to generate hashes only for the new 20 files I added and add the hashes to the existing csv without re hash the whole folder again
if it is possible can you Please edit my script
thanks

Comment: You have a file storing what's already been hashed.  Do you suppose that could be used to figure out what still needs to be hashed on subsequent runs?  What have you tried as far as that new requirement?

Comment: Try using `Get-ChildItem folder | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)}`. This will find all of the files in the directory that were modified in the last 7 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for files last updated **after** the csv file's last modified time.

Something like:

```
$csvFile = 'D:\MediaHashes.csv'
$csvDate = (Get-Item -Path $csvFile).LastWriteTime

Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\MyMediaFiles' -Recurse -Exclude '*.csv' -File | 
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $csvDate } |
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | 
Export-Csv -Path $csvFile  -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

An alternative is to import the csv `Path` column and hash only those files that are not in there yet:

```
$csvFile = 'D:\MediaHashes.csv'
# get an array of the files already hashed
$filesDone = (Import-Csv -Path $csvFile -UseCulture).Path

Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\MyMediaFiles' -Recurse -Exclude '*.csv' -File | 
Where-Object { $filesDone -notcontains $_.FullName } |
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | 
Export-Csv -Path $csvFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: If you want to get files modified in the last x amount of days you can also replace the `$csvDate` variable with `(Get-Date).AddDays(-<Amount of days>)`

Comment: The question is not clear if "new files" means "newly-_created_" or "newly-_added_ members of `D:\MyMediaFiles`", but for the latter case it'd certainly be possible for a file modified before the last run of the script to be copied or moved into `MyMediaFiles`.  Its `LastWriteTime` would not change and, therefore, this code would ignore it.

Comment: @BACON Good point. I have added an alternative using the files already listed in the csv.